# how to get value entered in UI created with the new HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

I can get/access the value of the UI elements using,

```
e.parameter.elementname or app.getElementById(id)
```

if i create UI using UiApps or GUI builder like,

```
app.add(app.loadComponent("MyGui"));
app.getElementbyId('textbox1').setText("Hi");
```

If i use, HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myPage'); 
How can i get the values entered in the html form - elements ?

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to client-side JavaScript, you can also create simple forms that submit to the `doPost()` handler which then processes the data. I created a sample script to demonstrate: [Run](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw7Hr3-6wRfHzyVAW_98mlXwpPk13ksHZn4rCY3HGMEyYiXJw8/exec), [Source](https://script.google.com/d/1i65oG_ymE1lreHtB6WBGaPHi3oLD_-wPd5Ter1nsN7maFAWgUA9DbE4C/edit)

Comment: why would my doPost() script redirect to an empty page? Even a simple thank you page containing just: <html><body><h1>Thank you!</h1></body></html>, is returning an empty screen?

Comment: actually even your example is not redirecting to the Thank you page but a blank page! What should be added to end of the doPost() function? I do not necessarily need a Thank you page, even a message on the same page would do.

Answer (score 5):

When using HtmlService you need to rethink your app to be primarily client based not server based. You can (in client-side JavaScript) add a change handler to any element and do something with the value, including calling a server function with google.script.run.myFunction(someValue). See the new user guide here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service