# Submit a Form using Google App Script's HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having issues calling the server side GAS function on form submission in a html form that was created using HtmlService. The HtmlService documentation says that the following should work:

```
<form id='myForm'>
  <input name='myFile' type='file'>
  <input name='aField'>

  <input type='button' onclick='google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode)'>
</form>
```

I'm using something similar:

```
<form id='approveForm'>
  <b>Enter Notes about this Approval : </b>
  <br /><br />
  <textarea id = 'approvalNotes' rows='10' cols='135'>Enter notes on this approval for future reference...</textarea>
  <br /><br />
  <b>Request Approved?</b>
  <br /><br />
  <input name = "decision" type="radio" id = 'rApproval' value='Yes'/>Yes<br />
  <input name = "decision" type="radio" id = 'rApproval' value ='No'/>No<br />
  <input name = "decision" type= "radio" id = 'rApproval' value='Pending'/>Pending<br />
  <br /><br />
  <b>Set the Group/List Type : </b>
  <br /><br />
  <input name = "gltype" type="radio" id = 'glType' value='Group'/>Group<br />
  <input name = "gltype" type="radio" id = 'glType' value='List'/>List<br />
  <input name = "gltype" type="radio" id = 'glType' value='?'/>?<br />
  <br />
  <input type='button' value='submit' onclick='google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode)'>
</form>
```

And though I have done almost the same thing that the documentation says will work for form submissions, my server side function doesn't get called. Can someone tell what I may be doing wrong and how I may be able to fix this.

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked fine. Only you might want to give the textarea input a name so that you can parse it.  Try adding Logger.log(JSON.stringify(form)); in your processForm function to verify if the form is passed and the function really gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this issue is being track at [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1660&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner), the form in HtmlService is having some problem. There is a workaround provided at "[how to get value entered in UI created with the new HtmlService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260247/how-to-get-value-entered-in-ui-created-with-the-new-htmlservice/11300412#11300412)" but it does not work well if you are going to do with files as it only works with text.