# Opening new html page when form is submitted using HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a form that I have implemented using HtmlService. When I submit it I want to see different Html page instead of the page with the form on it. Basically this new page should replace the form page. How do I go about doing this. I tried to create a template form from the process form function that gets called when the form is submitted. But it didn't work. Help me out with this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any server-side redirect mechanism (that you could use in the template, that is). However, one way how to do it is via Ajax, client-side. See, for example, how I did it in [VALET](https://script.google.com/d/1CwQEHJ-qbeRc743T-aIPlyBZpQFP7zaWmNjKQCioVZCr2MH2vTNPBwfw/edit) (open index.html and look from line 240 on).

As an aside: I also tried [reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript) a page which seemed not to work (maybe due to the restrictions re the `window` and `document` object.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697525/1677912) for an example of serving multiple html pages using HtmlService. The basic idea is to write `doGet()` to accept a query parameter that it will use to select which html page to serve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use doPost() with HTML Services to load another html page.

[See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300412)