# Linking to another HTML page in Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

When linking from ScriptDbConsole.html to legend.html I get the following error message:

> Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist. Please check the
>   address and try again.

This would normally work in a normal environment, but not here I guess. It's in script.google.com.

When creating a new .html file in script.google.com project, it creates it at the same location as it did for the others, so this code should actually work right? How can I open legend.html from ScriptDbConsole.html?

```
<a href='legend.html' target='_blank'>Open in new window</a>
```

Comment: I did the same a few days ago and it turned out the rendered link href value is http://script.google.com/legend.html, which is of course wrong. I ended up using the https://googledrive.com/host/"Public folder ID"/legend.html method and linked to the file. This is ok for me as I didn't need to run any code on the linked page, just display some info.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

While the HtmlService allows you to serve HTML, it is not "hosting" pages, and you cannot access the various html files in your Apps Script project by URL directly. Instead, your Web App will have a URL when it is published, and that is the only URL you have.

Here's a way that you can serve separate pages from your script, and have them behave similarly to html file links.

The `doGet()` function is passed an event when called, and we can take advantage of that to indicate which page we want served. If our Web App ID is `<SCRIPTURL>`, here is what a URL plus a querystring requesting a specific page will look like:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/<SCRIPTURL>/dev?page=my1
```

Using templated HTML, we can generate the necessary URL + querystring on the fly. In our `doGet()`, we just need to parse the querystring to determine which page to serve.

Here's the script, with two sample pages containing buttons to flip between them.

#### Code.gs

```
/**
 * Get the URL for the Google Apps Script running as a WebApp.
 */
function getScriptUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}

/**
 * Get "home page", or a requested page.
 * Expects a 'page' parameter in querystring.
 *
 * @param {event} e Event passed to doGet, with querystring
 * @returns {String/html} Html to be served
 */
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log( Utilities.jsonStringify(e) );
  if (!e.parameter.page) {
    // When no specific page requested, return "home page"
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('my1').evaluate();
  }
  // else, use page parameter to pick an html file from the script
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['page']).evaluate();
}
```

#### my1.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Source = my1.html</h1>
    <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=my2'> <input type='button' name='button' value='my2.html'></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### my2.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Source = my2.html</h1>
    <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=my1'> <input type='button' name='button' value='my1.html'></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's dirty...and beautifull at the same time. At least it's working.

Comment: I did copy and paste your code and here the result that i got: Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/a/vngates.vn/macros/s/AKfycbxfYkHPrTDQzXUygfNdSlkMNxc67Vj46Pt1mjbfVLH7/dev?page=my2' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: Found solution for my above error: you should add this to my1.html and my.html
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

So your my1.html will look like this:
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Source = my1.html</h1>
    <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=my2'> <input type='button' name='button' value='my2.html'></a>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: This may be a stupid question ... in my html, I have pasted _<?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=page2'> <input type='button' name='button' value='page2.html'></a>_.  On my page, the _<?var url = getScriptUrl();?>_ portion actually displays, with the button next to it, but it directs to a 400 Error, because the _<?var url = getScriptUrl();?>_ isn't resolving.  Why is it displaying, instead of calling the function?

Comment: Something important: this code.gs still needs the include function from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

Answer (score 7):

Google apps script web-app is  primarily designed to be used a single page web-app application, with dynamic pages. But it can be also used as a multiple page application(not recommended). Here's a sample web-app, which uses the change handler to get web pages using the url hash fragment(as opposed to templates in the previous answer).

#### Code.gs:

```
//@return Base Url
function getUrl() {
  return ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
}
//@return Html page raw content string
function getHtml(hash) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(hash).getContent()
}

//@return provided page in the urlquery '?page=[PAGEID]' or main index page
function doGet(e) {
  var page = e.parameter.page
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(page || 'index')
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setTitle('App Demo')
}
```

#### page1.html

```
<h3>This is Page 1</h3>
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

#### page2.html

```
<h4>This is Page2</h4>
<p>Goodbye World!</p>
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top" />
    <title>Single Page App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      h1 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 2px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-color: green;
      }
      span:hover,
      a:hover {
        background-color: yellowgreen;
      }
      body {
        background-color: brown;
        color: white;
        font-size: 2em;
      }
      a:visited {
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><span id="type">Single</span> Page App Demo</h1>
    <div id="main">Loading...</div>
    <script>
      //Change base url
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(url => {
          $('base').attr('href', url)
        })
        .getUrl()

      //Function to handle hash change
      function change(e) {
        let hash = e.location.hash
        if (!hash) {
          main()
          return
        }
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(htmlFragment => {
            $('#main').html(htmlFragment)
          })
          .getHtml(hash)
      }
      google.script.history.setChangeHandler(change)

      //Function to add Main page html
      function main() {
        $('#main').html(`
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#page1">Page1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#page2">Page2</a></li>
            </ul>`)
      }

      //Loads Main html from main function
      //Adds toggle to span to change to a Multiple page app
      $(() => {
        main()
        $('#type').on('click', () => {
          let hf = $('a').attr('href')
          if (!hf) return
          hf = hf.indexOf('#') + 1
          $('#type').text(hf ? 'Multiple' : 'Single')
          $('a').each((i, el) => {
            $(el).attr('href', (i, v) =>
              hf ? '?page=' + v.slice(1) : '#' + v.slice(6)
            )
          })
        })
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### References:

- [Web apps guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [setChangeHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/history#setChangeHandler(Function))

Comment: Good job, thanks a lot. And [this](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx1N1N0cL92hC-c1r70HyhnztaPdReX6vUCM2MiaD8dHHpGfZfH_UiVuMYe8qml_EWa5w/exec) is a live demo.

Comment: @MuhammetYunus Hope you tried clicking the "Single" on the top!

Answer (score 7):

## Multi Page Web App

This is working basic four page webapp.  It only displays the page title and four buttons on the left sidebar for navigation.

Code.gs:

```
function getScriptURL(qs) {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  //Logger.log(url + qs);
  return url + qs ;
}

function doGet(e) 
{
  //Logger.log('query params: ' + Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
  if(e.queryString !=='')
  {  
    switch(e.parameter.mode)
    {
      case 'page4':
        setPage('Page4')      
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page4')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page4"); 
        break;  
      case 'page3':
        setPage('Page3');        
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page3')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page3");
        break;
      case 'page2':
        setPage('Page2');        
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page2')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page2");
        break;  
      case 'page1':
         setPage('Page1');
         return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page1')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page1");
        break;
      default:
        setPage('Page1');
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page1')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page1");
        break;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    setPage('Page1');
    return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('Page1')
    .evaluate()
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setTitle("Page1");
  }
}

function getPageData()
{
  var s='';
  s+='<input type="button" value="Page1" onClick="getUrl(\'?mode=page1\');" />';
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Page2" onClick="getUrl(\'?mode=page2\');" />';
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Page3" onClick="getUrl(\'?mode=page3\');" />';
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Page4" onClick="getUrl(\'?mode=page4\');" />';
  var rObj={menu:s,title:getPage()};
  Logger.log(rObj);
  return rObj;
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

Pages.gs

I decided to switch to user scripts properties service since you may want to have more that one user.  I often develop scripts that only I use.

```
function setPage(page) {
  var ps=PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  ps.setProperty('PageTitle', page);
  return ps.getProperty('PageTitle');
}

function initPage() {
  var ps=PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  ps.setProperty('PageTitle','');
  return ps.getProperty('PageTitle');
}

function getPage() {
  var ps=PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var pt=ps.getProperty('PageTitle');
  return pt;
}
```

globals.gs:

I was using this for the page title but decided that some of you may wish to have multiple users and so user properties service is a more logical selection.  I'll probably use this for something else so I left it in.  But your call.

```
function getGlobals(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Globals');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,getGlobalHeight(),2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var g={};
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    g[vA[i][0]]=vA[i][1];
  }
  return g;
}

function setGlobals(dfltObj){
  if(dfltObj){
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Globals');
    var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,getGlobalHeight(),2);
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      vA[i][1]=dfltObj[vA[i][0]];
    }
    rg.setValues(vA);
  }
}

function getGlobal(key) {
  var rObj=getGlobals();
  if(rObj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    return rObj[key];
  }else{
    throw(Utilities.formatString('JJE-SimpleUtilitiesScripts-Error: Globals does not contain a key named %s.',key));
  }  
}

function setGlobal(key,value){
  var curObj=getGlobals();
  curObj[key]=value;
  setGlobals(curObj);
}

function getGlobalHeight(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Globals');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getMaxRows(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(!vA[i][0]){
      break;
    }
  }
  return i;
}
```

Page1.html:

1 of 4.  They start out the same. I make them this way and if I need to customize them I'll usually just do it right inside the html page.  But it's also possible to add additional javascript or css pages to support variations from page to page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('res') ?>
    <?!= include('css') ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?!= include('content') ?>
    <?!= include('script') ?>
  </body>
</html>
<html><head>
```

content.html:

```
    <div class="sidenav"></div>
    <div class="header">
      <h1 id="ttl"></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="main"></div>

script.html:

<script>
  $(function(){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(updatePageData)
    .getPageData();
  });
    function getUrl(qs){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(loadNewPage)
      .getScriptURL(qs);
    }
     function updatePageData(dObj){
      $('.sidenav').html(dObj.menu);
      $('.header #ttl').html(dObj.title);
    }
    function loadNewPage(url){
      window.open(url,"_top");
    }
    console.log('script.html');
</script>
```

css.html:

A very simple styles page.

```
<style>
input[type="button"],input[type="text"],label{margin:2px 2px 5px 5px;}
body {
  background-color:#fbd393;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #EEE;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}
.sidenav a:hover,label:hover {
  color: #770000;
}
.header{
  margin-left: 75px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 16px; 
  padding: 0px 5px;
  background-color:#fbd393;
  height:60px;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 75px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 5px;
  background-color:#e9e8de;
  height:450px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 5px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 16px;}
}

</style>
```

res.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Animation:

[image]