# How to use href in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

```
<label>
    <input type="button" onclick="abc()" id="log" value='SUBMIT'>
</label>
<script>
    function abc() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).processForm(document.forms[0]);
    }

    function callback(ste) {
        if (ste == "true") {
            var a = document.getElementById('log');
            document.write(a.value);
            document.write('<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp">do stuff</a>');
        } else document.write("false");
    }
</script>
```

as i m using document.location && window.location both are not working to switch page,is there any other method which can help me out to

Comment: Where you are using document.location?

Comment: Am not sure, I did understand your querstion.

Comment: i have used instead of document.write,but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've left clues, including the [[image]google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) tag and the call to `google.script.run`, but your question should make it clearer that this code is being hosted from the Google Apps Script environment. That limits the solution, as described in the documentation for [Class HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output).

You are trying to redirect the browser to a new URL, which is not allowed in Apps Script web apps.<sup>[ref](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2003#c1)</sup>

That means that none of the other provided javascript solutions will work. Your work-around of presenting the user with a clickable link is your only option for redirecting to an "external" URL. (external == not your web app)

You can provide the illusion of a redirect to another html page within your Apps Script WebApp, though. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697525/1677912) for an example of serving multiple html pages using HtmlService. The basic idea is to write `doGet()` to accept a query parameter that it will use to select which html page to serve.

Comment: yeah that's true that environment is in Google Apps Script,thanks alot for that

Comment: but i got how do we use :<?var url=getScriptUrl();?>
<a href='<?=url?>?page=form'>
in any conditional operator...

Comment: ok..as you mention that in your link
 <?var url=getScriptUrl();?>
<a href='<?=url?>?page=form'>
        <label><input type="button" onclick="abc()" id="log" value='SUBMIT' class= "btn btn-danger"></label>
</a>
that's true that is directly working for the button...

but i need that in "if" statement like...

function abc(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).processForm(document.forms[0]);
}

function callback(ste){
if(ste=="true"){
alert("i LOGIN");
//wanted switch my page here
}
else
alert("Login Failed!!");
}

Comment: yeah i also done this...u r right that's not possible...actually i was trying to make a login page...without using session...so little things gone nasty..thank you so much by the way..

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
 window.location.href
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function callback(ste) {
        if (ste == "true") {
            var a = document.getElementById('log');
            location.href='http://yoursite.com';
//or put your url into var and put it there
        } else document.write("false");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple thing. Before askin you should do research.

You can use:

```
function callback(ste) {
        if (ste == "true") {
            var a = document.getElementById('log');
            window.location.href='http://yoursite.com';
//or put your url into var and put it there
        } else document.write("false");
    }
```

if you are not sure about anything please comment.

http://www.sivamdesign.com/scripts/navigate.html there are a few examples which shows the scripts on how it works

Comment: it is not working ..window.location.href and location.href,both are not working..and if i m doing like document.write('<a href="http://yoursite.com';">link</a>');
if i do like that it goes to the next page and shows the link and then have to click on that

Comment: what is it that you want to do?

Comment: means..i just wanted to switch directly to another page,

Comment: but your window.location.href and location.href is not working,

Comment: you may want to use firebug to debug your javaScript because it should work the only issue i can think of is that you have a function with an error

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?var url=getScriptUrl();?>
    <a href='<?=url?>?page=form'>
           <label><input type="button" onclick="abc()" id="log" value='SUBMIT' class= "btn btn-danger"></label>
    </a>
    </form>

<script>
function abc(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).processForm(document.forms[0]);
}

function callback(ste){
if(ste=="true"){
alert("i LOGIN");
// want to switch it here
}
else
alert("Login Failed!!");
}
```