# How can I get url parameters from a google sites page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

For a Google site, I want a page to display content based on the url parameters.

Eg. http://sites.google.com/../mypage?id=123

Then I want to make a HTTP request using the id and display the result on the page.

Or I want to use App Scripts to perform something and display the result on the page.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 3):

Use on Google app script

```
function doGet(e){
// id in your Url. example :   http://sites.google.com/../mypage?myidok=123
var element - e.parameters.myidok

// code 
// your app 

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the new google sites when embedding a google script.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697525/1677912) for an example of serving multiple html pages using HtmlService. The basic idea is to write doGet() to accept a query parameter that it will use to select which html page to serve.