# Webapp to return specific text responses for a URL parameter

Tags: google-apps-script

I am sorry cause I do not know any scripting language I am posting my concerns here. I am in need of script having the below functionality. I have created https://sites.google.com/site/iitmamritwater website.

I am in need a web service for a HTTP GET request like : https://sites.google.com/site/iitmamritwater?id=xxxxxxxxxx that would validate id as submitted in query param. Currently I have only 2 valid ID values each of 10 digits length. The web service response should state id validity with its balance - something like below:

```
If xxxxxxxxxx is one of the two possible correct values then response should be as below:

https://sites.google.com/site/iitmamritwater?id=xxxxxxxxxx

V;10.50;

If xxxxxxxxxy is not one of the two values then response should be as below:

https://sites.google.com/site/iitmamritwater?id=xxxxxxxxxy

N;00.00;
```

Its a very simple script but cause I do not know scripting I am stuck implementing the concept. I don't know even how to begin with - can some one please post the code for same - it would be highly helpful for me? It will save my project development time period.

Comment: You are on SO since 2010 and you know nothing about scripting ?  No personal offense but at least you should know that this is not the right place to ask someone to do it for you. Try the Google-apps-Script community on G+ instead, maybe you'll be more lucky.

Comment: @Sergeinsas I know scripting but not Google Apps Scripting. It seems that Google Apps scripting is not like PHP / NodeJS or C/C++. It seems one has to do some coding in Java - hence the concern as I do not know that language very well - to get a request, get the param, validate the params and generate a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697525/1677912) for an example of serving multiple html pages using HtmlService. The basic idea is to write `doGet()` to accept a query parameter that it will use to select which html page to serve.

In your case, instead of serving HTML pages, you should use the [`ContentService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) to output the appropriate response, based on the evaluation of the received parameters.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  if (!e.parameter.id) {
    // No id provided...
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Error - no id');
  }

  // else, get response for given id
  var response = validateId( e.parameter.id );

  // ...and serve it as text output
  return ContentService.createTextOutput( response );
}

/**
 * Get a response string for the given id
 *
 * @param {string}      id   10 digit id
 * @returns {string}         Result of validation & lookup
 */

function validateId( id ) {
  return "Under construction";
}
```