# Using a Google Web App - Can I pass a variable from one HTML page to another within the same web app

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-apps-script, global-variables

I have created a Google Web App.  It has 2 HTML pages that I can switch between using the principles described in this answer from Stack Overflow

[Linking to another HTML page in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script/16697525#16697525)

The first HTML page calls a server side function. It returns data from a Google spreadsheet and assigns the data to a variable.

When a user switches to HTML page 2 the variable is lost and so when switching back to page 1 the script must call the server side function again, which takes a few seconds.

Is it possible to maintain the variable for the full session?

I've tried assigning it as as a global variable in the HTML files, as a global var in the .gs file, and passing it as a parameter in the URL but none of these seem to work.

I suspect it's not possible due to the nature of the apps script HTML service but you never know...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the variable using the [WebStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

---

If storage capacity is an issue then I would recommend using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). Its a NoSQL database built into most modern browsers. The API can be a bit complex to handle so you may want to leverage a framework like [Dexie](http://dexie.org/)