# Multi-page site in Google Apps Script: How to invoke doGet() through jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I want to build multi-page sites using Google Apps Script. To do this, I would like to exploit the ability of `doGet()` to process query strings. I am aware of at least one solution to this problem:

[Linking to another HTML page in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script/16697525#16697525)

However, that solution seems overly restrictive, since it relies on GAS's [templated html feature](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) to build the proper URL with query string right within the HTML at page load-time. A more general-purpose solution would be to build the appropriate query string within a jquery (or javascript) function based on dynamic UI state and user interface actions. Is this possible? How can it be done?

Here is my proposal for a possible solution (which doesn't work!):

HTML/JQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Speedgolf Scoring</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id = "mainBody">
    <H1>LOGIN PAGE</H1>
    <H3>Please choose interface:</H3>
    <button id = "playerUI">Follow Player</button>
    <button id = "holeUI">Follow Hole</button>
    <button id = "flexUI">Roaming Scorer</button>
  </body>
</html>

<script>

  function loadNewPage(result, userObject) {
    var newURL = result + userObject;
    alert("Newly-constructed URL to be loaded: " + newURL); //CORRECT URL IS CONSTRUCTED BASED ON DEBUGGING OUTPUT!
    window.open(newURL,"_self"); //<--THIS IS THE LINE THAT SHOULD INVOKE DOGET(). SERVER LOGS INDICATE DOGET() IS INVOKED, BUT NO PAGE IS VISIBLY SERVED.
  }

  $("#playerUI").click(function () {
  alert("In player UI click...");
  var newURL = "?mode=player";
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadNewPage).withUserObject(newURL).getScriptURL();
  //Execution continues in loadNewPage callback...
  });

  $("#holeUI").click(function () {
   var newURL = "?mode=hole";
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadNewPage).withUserObject(newURL).getScriptURL();
  });

   $("#flexUI").click(function () {
    var newURL = "?mode=flex";
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadNewPage).withUserObject(newURL).getScriptURL();
  });

</script>
```

And my Code.gs file:

```
function getScriptURL() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  Logger.log('In getScriptURL...Value of URL returned: ' + url);
  return url;
}


function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log('In doGet');
  Logger.log('query params: ' + Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
  if (e.queryString === '') {
    Logger.log('Serving loginUI');
    return HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('loginUI')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setTitle("Please log in");
  }
  //if here, we know query string is NOT null
  if (e.parameter.mode == "player") {
    Logger.log('Serving player UI');
    return HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('playerUI')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setTitle("Following Player");
  }
  if (e.parameter.mode == "hole") {
    Logger.log('Serving hole UI');
    return HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('holeUI')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setTitle("Following Hole");
  } 
  if (e.parameter.mode == "flex") {
    Logger.log('Serving flex UI');
    return HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('flexUI')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setTitle("Flex Interface");
  }
}
```

I am able to verify, through server logs and alert boxes, that the correct URL with query string is built. I would expect this line of code:

```
$("#mainBody").load(newURL);
```

to invoke `doGet()` and cause a new page to be loaded based on the query string. However, through my server logs, I observe that `doGet()` is not invoked, and hence the new page I expect to be served is never served. What is happening? Why is `doGet()` not invoked when I load a new page through jquery? How can I force `doGet()` to be invoked? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would have expected your script tag to be with the head tags or perhaps even the body tags. But not outside of the html tags.

Comment: @Cooper, would that make a difference?

Comment: Thanks for that comment about the `window.open(url,"_top");`  I kind of had it working before but with that addition it seems pretty bullet proof.

Comment: `<head><base target="_top"></head>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha! The above code *will* work properly if you change

```
window.open(newURL,"_self");
```

to

```
window.open(newURL,"_top");
```

I am not sure why "_top" is necessary, but in the example code above, it makes all the difference: doGet() is invoked with the proper query string, resulting in the expected page being served. Hooray! This approach to serving new web pages on the fly provides a powerful alternative to templated HTML. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I ended up using in the basic html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Speedgolf Scoring</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

  function loadNewPage(url) {
    //window.location.href = url;
    window.open(url,"_top");
  }

  function getUrl(qs)
  {
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(loadNewPage)
        .getScriptURL(qs);
  }

console.log('MyCode');
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <H3>Please choose interface:</H3>
    <input type="button" value="All Sheets" onClick="getUrl('?mode=allsheets');" />
    <input type="button" value="One Sheet" onClick="getUrl('?mode=onesheet');" />
    <input type="button" value="Return to Main" onClick="getUrl('');" />
  </body>
</html>
```

And my gs code now looks like this:

```
function getScriptURL(qs) {

  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  Logger.log(url + qs);
  return url + qs ;
}


function doGet(e) 
{
  Logger.log('query params: ' + Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
  if(e.queryString !=='')
  {  
    switch(e.parameter.mode)
    {
      case 'onesheet':
        return HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutputFromFile('onesheet')
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
        .append('<br />onesheet')
        .setTitle("One Sheet"); 
        break;
      case 'allsheets':
         return HtmlService
         .createHtmlOutputFromFile('allsheets')
         .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
         .append('<br />allsheets')
         .setTitle("All Sheets");
        break;
      default:
         return HtmlService
         .createHtmlOutputFromFile('speedgolferah')
         .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
         .append('<br />No Query String')
         .setTitle("Main Page");
        break;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return HtmlService
         .createHtmlOutputFromFile('speedgolferah')
         .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
         .append('<br />No Query String')
         .setTitle("Main Page");
  }
}
```

I have some other pages I threw in because I had them.  One displays all of my sheets and one displays just the one I select.  But yeh I'd been putting this off for a while and I was good to get in there and start messing with the multiple payge solution for the doGet again.

But thanks for the `window.open(url,"_top");` that made a lot of difference.  Thanks.