# how to set up a simple web page within the google app script (or by pass the limitation of hosting single html file)?)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to set up a web application that contains 2 html pages. One is the login page and another present the data. However, I have difficulty re-loading or doing DOM manipulation once the user click the login button (which called a server-side function). I have read from previous instruction that google app script could only host one HTML and dose not support DOM manipulation. I tried to do reload the page but it dose not work. Is there any way to bypass the limitation ?

Comment: An Apps Script Web App *can* do DOM manipulation.  You can implement page navigation.  You can retrieve content from the server after the Web App has loaded and inject that content into the HTML.  You can load different content when the Web App first loads depending upon a search string ending on the URL.  Trying to cover all of those topics and more is basically a tutorial, not a specific programming answer.

Comment: Post a minimal version of your server-side JavaScript and HTML files.  One issue you may be having is if your button is inside of a <form>.  In that case, you need to make sure to catch the `submit` event and call `.preventDefault` as explained in the Apps Script documentation.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940930/multi-page-site-in-google-apps-script-how-to-invoke-doget-through-jquery-or-j/46943386#46943386