# how to redirect to another html page of the google apps script project after login successfully?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

In the google apps script project, from javascript code, if the login is TRUE, i want to display the another html form page of same apps script project.

JavaScript:

```
function LoginUser()
    {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) 
    {
      if(output == 'TRUE')
      {
         //if login successfully, I want to display html page from apps script project   
      }
      else if(output == 'FALSE')
      {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Invalid data";     
      }    
    }).checkLogin(username, password);
    }
```

I am new in google apps script. so I can't .gs code that. I searched in google to help, but there not available code about that, Please help me for .gs coding of my problem.

Comment: What does is your original page HTML?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46943386/7215091

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of inserting another HTML file into the original page.  the `div` `otherPage` is empty until Submit button is clicked and will recieve the new HTML from HTML_OtherPage

**HTML_Test**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="username" type="text">
    <label for="username">User Name</label><br>
    <input id="password" type="text">
    <label for="password">Password</label><br>
    <input id="submitbutton" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="loginUser()"><br>
    <div id="otherpage">
    </div>
    <input id="errorMessage" type="text" readonly>
    <script>
      function loginUser() {
        try {
          let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
          let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
            function(response) {
              if( response.status ) {
                document.getElementById("otherpage").outerHTML = response.html;
              }
              else {
                document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Invalid data";
              }
            }
          ).checkLogin(username, password);
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**HTML_OtherPage**

```
<input id="pageHtml" type="text" value="Hello"><br>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function checkLogin(username,password) {
  let response = {}
  response.status = true;
  response.html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTML_OtherPage").getContent();
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Your code run successfully. but, I want more that  when submit button is clicked, other page will display and the submit form page will disappear or dismiss, and Logout button will display up right corner of the other page to Logout. and when Logout , the login/submit page will appear. Please help me.

Comment: I've given you the backbone of a way to insert another page. The same technique can be used to replace the entire page.