# ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() is returning null, after publishing the App

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

my return type of the following code is returning null even when my code is deployed as web app,

```
ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
```

I was trying to link multiple HTML in my google script based application, and I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script/16697525#16697525)

for doing this, however when I checked my return type in the below code, it was retuning null

```
function getScriptUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 Logger.log(url);
 return url;
}
```

According to the documentation mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service), 
it should return null only if my code is not deployed, but my code is already deployed and I deployed it from Publish>Deploy as web App, I also check the deployment by changing the version but nothing is working out for me.

Comment: that was my initial step, when the code was not working for me, I figured out this issue, here Logger should return the script URL

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue. Do you have "This Project is published" at the bottom of the script editor?