# Is there a type definition for the doGet/doPost trigger function event object?

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, web-applications, triggers, clasp

I am trying to turn a Google Script into a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), using CLASP.

Is there an existing type definition for the "e" object in `doGet(e)` / `doPost(e)` that I can use in the typescript /clasp side of things?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Update:

[Latest definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google-apps-script/google-apps-script-events.d.ts) include `events`.
You may use events like this:

```
function doGet(e: GoogleAppsScript.Events.DoGet){
```

---

<strike>`Events` seem to be in the [works](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google-apps-script/google-apps-script-events.d.ts). It doesn't have webapps doget event yet. In the mean time, You can install the latest type(@types/google-apps-script@latest) and add the following interface in the Events module inside google-apps-script-events.d.ts</strike>

```
  export interface WebAppsDoGet { //should be inside module Events
    queryString: string,
    parameter: {[key: string]: string; },
    contextPath: string,
    parameters: {
     [key: string]: string[]; },
    contentLength: number
  }
```

You can then use it like this:

```
function doGet(e: GoogleAppsScript.Events.WebAppsDoGet){
```

Comment: Why is this all crossed out? Is there an update? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script suggests that you could use something from the event e to choose between two HTML to show but what is the contents of the webapp event? Where is it documented? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web Are 'webapps' really apps if they are meant to only have one HTML page?

Comment: @aNewb It's striked because the "the works" are finished and you have the latest type definitions link in the update above. The contents of the `e` are documented under "Request parameters" in the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) you provided. My answer in the question you linked also provides a full demo of the webapp capabilities.