# How to set default homepage on multiple html files in google appscript and publish it as WebApp

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

Set a default main page on multiple html and GS(googlescript) files on Google Appscript,and Im going to publish it as a Web App

tried doGet function???

Comment: Here's an example of a multipage webapp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You need to implement doGet function.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params);
}
```

Please refer to the official page below for details.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Thanks mate!appreciate it