# How to do sub pages in Google apps script web apps

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to make subpages with HTML in apps script How do I link the user to a subpage

I tried an href on the homepage

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css.html">
  </body>
  <a href="/subpage.html">Click me!</a>
```

I expect the subpage.html link to take me to a subpage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking to another HTML page in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091

Answer (score -1):

I was searching as well on how to work with subpages but unfortunately it seems like Google's HTML services have this option available.

You can create several HTML files and use `div` for each of the child pages to show/hide the `div` corresponding to the subpage you want to show.

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding a code sample to give OP and future visitors a clear idea of how to resolve the problem presented in the question.