# Share App Script Web App Between Multiple Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a web app using app script linked to a Google Sheet. I would like to distribute this script to multiple users, but I would like for each user to have an instanced version of the sheet.

The script is authenticating users with OAuth to a third party API and returning data based on that user's permission level, thus why the sheets need to be unique to the user, but using the same script.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I edited my answer to include something that might be more helpful for you in the long run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the [Google Apps Script Dashboard](https://script.google.com/home) you're able to create a standalone script. After pasting your code in there, if you go to `File > Manage Versions` you'll be greeted with a prompt to enter a description and a button that says `Save new version`. After entering the description you'd like, go ahead and click the button.

Now you'll want to copy this part of the url of your script (which is your script ID) [image: Script ID]
and in the desired spreadsheets, in the script editor, select `Resources > Libraries` and enter your link into this box

[image: Add Library]

After adding it, select your version (I didn't enter a description for this one, however if you do enter a description when making your project version, it will appear next to the version number).
[image]

Hit save and now you'll be able to access functions from the library you've created like so
[image: Using the library]

You'll know it's working properly if it brings up suggestions after you type the period like this
[image: Suggestions from library]

### Edit

I just realized you mentioned it's a web app, in which case there's a different way you can do this - you'll still want it as a standalone script, but what you can do is to pass a sheet ID based on the user accessing the web app. I personally don't have experience with OAuth, however I have connected a single web-app to different sheets depending on a drop down before.

How I accomplished this is as such:

I first set the value of the drop down in the html to include the sheet ID I wanted to send it to (changed a few things since this is from company code)

```html
<option value="1THvC8JhF-LxZOYBGRaIvpZpYoNtyfOuteWNPndtrCQo@[Title of the page]">[Option to select]</option>
```

Then in the Javascript I set the url to include the title and ID when it redirects to the next page

```
function boxVal(url){
  var ID = document.getElementById('[ID of select]').value;
  var strArr = ID.split('@');
  ID = strArr[0];
  var title = strArr[1];
  if(ID === "Select Your Department"){
    url += "?page=Department Select&title=" + title;
  }
  else{
    url += "?page=Main Page&title=" + title + "&id=" + ID;
  }
  document.getElementById('link').href = url;
  document.getElementById('link').click();
}
```

(for reference as to how I have multiple pages if you don't already know, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697525/11826524))

Then in the `doGet()` function I grabbed the id paramater that I passed to the URL that I could then pass to my functions in the javascript

```
var qString = e.parameter['id'];
uProps('SPREADSHEET_ID', qString);
```

where `uProps` is

```
function uProps(prop, propVal){
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty(prop ,propVal);
}
```

Which creates a user property that can be referenced after the page changes.

Then back to the javascript connected to the html file I use this to pass the user properties to other functions

```
function passFunction(receiver){
  switch(receiver) {
    case 1: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(add).getProps('SPREADSHEET_ID'); break;
    case 2: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getTopInterrupt).getProps('SPREADSHEET_ID'); break;
  }
}
```

where `passFunction` executes from an `onclick` in the html

This is the `.getProps` function which is in the Code.gs file (the one I have containing the doGet())

```
function getProps(prop){
  return PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty(prop);
}
```

I think if you can get this to work with your OAuth system, then this would be the best route to go, as you could have a single version of the web app serving all your users without having to put any code in the other sheets.

Hope this helps

Comment: There's a lot of info here so I am still taking a deeper look at it, but basically I am using the original AppScript as almost a proxy server for my oauth flow and I can use it to distribute access/refresh tokens back to the individual sheets using their sheet IDs? Thanks for the thorough answer!!

Comment: @GeorgeWright Apologies for the late reply - I hadn't thought about it that way before, but perhaps it's a good explanation of what's going on, since the pages both end up communicating to the file the `doGet` is in, which in turns communicates with (and I'll be honest I don't really know) wherever the user properties are stored. And no problem, always glad to offer up information on something I have experience with.

Comment: Awesome... Thanks!