# Fail to initialize when changing inner html (google app script)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

(original question)

I'm now trying to develop a web app through App Script using Materialize layout and components.

As I wanted to create a nav-bar that contains different page buttons (which should change the body part of the site), I found the elements within each site are not working well. I tried to create routes of sites using `doGet(e)` and some `if-else` arguments, which works just fine, but that renders a whole new page instead of keeping the nav-bar above still. I'm wondering if there's a way to do so... (I'm guessing it's the way I change innerHTML being wrong.)

As for now, the main page shows normal. However, when I click the "A" button on the nav-bar (and it shows a date picker below), it's now popping a picker as it supposed to.

(0327 Update)

I'm sorry for any misleading of my question. I tried to simplify my question below with the updated code that contains only my situations here.

The page below is a mainPage that contains a "datePicker1" element, and when I click the "Page A" button above, a new "datePicker2" is written into the DOM content. However, "dP1" works well, which pops its calendar as it supposed to, but "dP2" is not. :(

(P.S. I think I was not clear enough: for the "nav-bar" mentioned before, I was hoping it works as a header in an HTML.)

Here's my code (updated):

**(mainPage.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html language="en">
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
    
  <body>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <header>
      <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav>
          <div class="nav-wrapper teal darken-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col s10 offset-s1">
                <div class="brand-logo">Logo</div>
                <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                  <li><a onClick="pageSelect(0);">Page A</a></li>
                  <li><a onClick="pageSelect(1);">Page B</a></li>
                  <li><a onClick="pageSelect(2);">Page C</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        Dateinput 1:
        <div class="input-field">
          <label for="dateinput1">Dateinput 1</label>
          <input id="dateinput1" type="text" class="datepicker">
        </div><br>
        Dateinput2:
        <div id="pageContent">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
      });
    </script>
    <script>
      function changeContent(content){
        document.getElementById("pageContent").innerHTML = content;
      }
      function pageSelect(index){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changeContent).getPage(index);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**(pageA.html)**

```
<div class="input-field">
  <label for="dateinput2">Dateinput 2</label>
  <input id="dateinput2" type="text" class="datepicker">
</div>
```

**(backend.gs)**

```
var mainPage = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("mainPage");

function doGet() {
  return mainPage.evaluate()
  .setTitle("mainPage")
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function getPage(index){
  let pageName;
  switch(index){
    case 0: pageName = "pageA"; break;
    case 1: pageName = "pageB"; break;
    case 2: pageName = "pageC"; break;
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(pageName).getContent();
}
```

I've tried to solve this on my own and been searching, still not getting any further...
Hope I'm making myself clear, thanks a lot!

Comment: Typically the nav bar is part of each page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091

Comment: @YvesC - Could you attach screenshot of `that renders a whole new page instead of keeping the nav-bar above still.`? I tried to replicate your code and nav-bar is working just fine.

Comment: @Cooper, thanks for the reference. I think that I was not that clear before. I wanted to use the `<nav>` as a header that keeps on top of the page, as the updated code shows.

Comment: @NikkoJ. Thanks for your checking, I updated my question and code above, please check them out. Thx a lot :)

Comment: Ok well it looks like you already have that so what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the elements of your web app to your browser, you can see in `dateinput1` that there is appended modal and the injected date picker(*dateinput2*) does not have. During the build process, if the materialize.js found a `datepicker` class in your html, it will append the `datepicker-modal` class that shows the date picker when the text box is clicked.

But since your script injected the `dateinput2` after the build process, it wont get the datepicker-modal. This causes your script not to show the datepicker.

Alternative solution is include the dateinput2 in your main html file and use the style property `display` to hide and show the date picker box. By this, we can ensure that the dateinput2 has modal for showing the datepicker.

[image]

### Reference:

- [Style display Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp)