# How to deploy multi google wep apps with different arguments with the same script automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to pass different arguments to one script and deploy the script as multi apps simultaneously

Comment: Here's a multipage webapp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log('query params: ' + Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
  if (e.queryString !== '') {
    switch (e.parameter.mode) {
      case 'dable':
        deleteAllEmailsNotWhiteListed();
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("delete black list Done!!!!");
        break;
      default:
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("<h1>Unknown Command: " + e.parameter.mode);
    }
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("No Query String");
  }
}
```