# Second HTML from Google doc crashes layout

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

In my Google Application Script web I am loading dynamically Google Doc as HTML. If I insert second HTML exactly the same way then it crashes the layout.

You can test it [here](https://script.google.com/a/macros/rsness.com/s/AKfycbzb3dTnh_Hacdh5e_w-fJGNP4u7eSrhe_1SuUjYOuG9M4QTdn6jydJ82A9bwOho0qEOcQ/exec)

**Test scenario 1**

- Load page
- wait till see the text (file 1 is loaded)
- go to the other tab and load file2
- go back to the first tab and the layout is different (the error is not consistent in terms when and how it performs)

**Test scenario 2**

- Load page
- wait till see the text (file 1 is loaded)
- load file 3
- check the bottom of the page. New test appears and everything is ok

**Test scenario 3**

- Load page
- wait till see the text (file 1 is loaded)
- load file 3
- check the bottom of the page. New test appears and everything is ok
- go to the other tab and load file2
- go back to the first tab and the layout is different (the error is not consistent in terms when and how it performs)

Server side code looks like. **NOTE** that from file3 are removed `<head>` tags.

Could someone explain and hopefully suggest a solution to this issue?

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
}


  function getGoogleDocumentAsHTML(file){
console.log(file)
if (file == 1){
     var docID ="1vRMY6bIkUc_J6qDOUJszIYAtIWH-aHTdYYgCmlL4"
}
if (file == 2 || file == 3){
     var docID ="1VBpazC3SO2hx4PA7r3A2jud5O9-teNu0nvvnIDac"
}

    var forDriveScope = DriveApp.getStorageUsed(); //needed to get Drive Scope requested



    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+docID+"&exportFormat=html&format=html";
    var param = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions:true,
    };
    var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText()

   // return cleanHTML(html)

if (file == 3 ){
    return cleanHTML(html)
}


    return html
    //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).getContent()
  }


function cleanHTML(html){

    // nuke the whole head section, including the stylesheet and meta tag
    html = html.replace(/<head>.*<\/head>/, '');
    // remove almost all html attributes
//    html = html.replace(/ (id|style|start|colspan|rowspan)="[^"]*"/g, '');
//    html = html.replace(/ (id|class|style|start|colspan|rowspan)="[^"]*"/g, '');
    // remove all of the spans, as well as the outer html and body
//    html = html.replace(/<(span|\/span|body|\/body|html|\/html)>/g, '');
    // clearly the superior way of denoting line breaks
//    html = html.replace(/<br>/g, '<br />');

return html

}
```

and html part is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_self">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.9.3/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.9.3/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.9.3/css/materialize/tabulator_materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>  


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <ul class="tabs" id="tabsTest">
          <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">HTML from file - loaded</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Second to be loaded</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="test1" class="col s12">
        <button id ="testingAdmin" class="waves-effect btn" onClick="getHTML(2)">Load second HTML</button>
        <div id="test" class="container col s12"> </div>
      </div>
      <div id="test2" class="col s12">
                <button id ="testingAdmin" class="waves-effect btn" onClick="getHTML(3)">Load third HTML</button>
        <div id="testovani" class="container col s12"></div>
        <div id="test3" class="container col s12"> </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function getHTML(file){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function(output){
            if (file == 1){
                document.getElementById("testovani").innerHTML = output
            }
            if (file == 2){
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = output
            }
            if (file == 3){
                document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = output
            }
          }
        ).getGoogleDocumentAsHTML(file);
      }

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        
        var options ={}
        var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs')

        var tabsOptions = {
          onShow : function(e) {
    console.log(e.id)
            switch (e.id){
              case "test2": 
              console.log("testing")
                break;
              default: 
            }
          } 
        }
      var instance = M.Tabs.init(tabs, options);
      getHTML(1)

        });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091

Comment: @Cooper, it does help me with my GAS application in general. Not sure how it is related to my "issue".