# Getting a blank page when navigating between GAS web pages

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, template-engine

I am building a multipage web app using GAS.
The actual URLs for the pages of my app are generated by my GAS and passed via the data variable to my html template.
A scriptlet is inserting the URL into the html template:

```
 <a href="<?= data.urlVUS ?>" >User</a>
```

The problem is: The first time I click on the link the page is loaded. The second or third time I click the link I see just a blank browser page.

There is no error in my GAS log or in the browser that indicates what is wrong.

My GAS is using

```
return myPage.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

I am not sure if it is contributing to the problem, but I am embedding the web app via an iframe within a Wordpress page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091  Just make one of the pages blank

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking to another HTML page in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script)