# Switching from one HTML page to another as a result of a .js if statement

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

thanks for helping a beginner on this one. Have a piece of code sitting in home-js.html (shown below) which is called at the base of a home.html code. Am performing some checks which if valid I want the user to be sent to the next page (mTeam.html) in my process (also coded within the same overall google script file set). Clearly the below isn't working - all advice gratefully received. Thanks!

```
   if(allValid){
         
         return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("mTeam").getContent();
  }
```

Comment: HtmlService is a server side google apps script service not Javascript for an html page

Comment: Here's a link to a multipage webapp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091

Comment: Thanks everyone - appreciate - will work with those

Answer (score 1):

On your javascript file that is sourced in your current html page, use this

```
document.location.href = "mTeam.Html";
```