# doGet() doing multiple things

Tags: google-apps-script

So, my question seems confuse at first because I can't find any direct reference about doGet() and doPost(), I can find it on specific documentations like the webApp one so I am having hard time grasping how doGet() works, that said...

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('INTERFACE/INICIAR/AcessoHTML')
      .evaluate();
}
```

I am using the code above to start my webApp, I have two doubts here:

1. This will start the landing page of the webApp (A login page), how can I change the page after the login? (point out to another html. I know I can use createTemplateFromFile and evaluate() to generate the page itself
2. doGet() is used to access the params of an HTML form, right? But I am returning the html page here, from what I found I would need to return the params I get from the submitted form but I am already returning another thing and as far I know you cannot have two return in the same function nor two doGet() on the same project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091

Comment: Are you familiar with if else or switch statements?

Comment: @cooper yes, I am

Comment: Can you imagine their use such as to provide the capability for multiple returns in a given function?  If not then please look at the link that I provided in my first comment

Comment: Hi, I provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72039510) to this. I hope it is useful to you.

Comment: TY, I can't upvote yet but TY

Comment: You cannot upvote but you can accept it. Just click the checkmark icon below the vote buttons https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

#### Multiple pages:

You can query the webapp URL with certain request parameters, for example:

```
const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
const paramUrl = `${url}?path=afterLogin`;
```

Now accessing this `paramUrl` will fire the `doGet` function, and the request parameters (`path=afterLogin`) will be accessible through the `doGet` function argument.

Here's a very simple example:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter["path"] === "afterLogin") {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('AFTER_LOGIN_HTML_FILE').evaluate();
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('INTERFACE/INICIAR/AcessoHTML').evaluate();
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)