# Getting another page without requiring access

Tags: google-apps-script

I am learning google apps script, and I have tried very hard to learn more. Right now I have a problem with opening another page, I deployed my app but when I click the button it shows me "need access" even though it is in my account (the funny thing is when I do that it send me a message about me want access).
I tried my own code and I tried this one:
[Linking to another HTML page in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script)

They both have the same problem for me, is there any solution for it, please ?

I tried my own code and this code:
[Linking to another HTML page in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script)