# GAS Web App- submit form to another form and submit again returning value under the submit button

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

After minimizing this code I was able to see the 2nd time it is submitted is when it will not change to the new page. It appends the data under the submit button. Why is this happening? What can I do to get it to open the page properly as it does on the first submit.

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
       <form id="mainform">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

    <script>

    var loginForm = document.getElementById("mainform");
    loginForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changePage).changeIt('success')

  
});

  function changePage(page) {
    document.write(page);
}  

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

success.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
 <body>

  success!!
       <form id="mainform">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

    <script>

    var loginForm = document.getElementById("mainform");
    loginForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changePage).changeIt('3rd')

  
});

  function changePage(page) {
    document.write(page);
}  

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

3rd.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    3rd Page should be blank but instead is showing underthe submit button.
  </body>
</html>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test.html')
  
}

function changeIt(page) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(page).getContent()
  
}
```

Comment: do you have an html file in your project named `success.html`?

Comment: yes I do, I can add it on post

Comment: Okay that's great but how do you plan to get a blank page if you're always ask for the success page.

Comment: I guess I dont understand, when the users fills out the form and hits submit I want it to be the success.html - I think I have drilled down more to my issue- I will update the code and question title-

Comment: Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091) to a multi page web app

Comment: See [warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Comment: @themaster Thank you for this, can you provide a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [MDN, `document.write` behavior is idiosyncratic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) and therefore not recommended. To  replace the entire page, use `innerHTML` on a specific element like the `body` using `getElementBy*` or the root element `html` using [`documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement).

```
function changePage(page) {
  document.documentElement.innerHTML = page;//Make sure page isn't user entered
  //document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = page
}
```

Do note that using `innerHTML`  is a security risk, if `page` is user entered/modified. Make sure that the source is secure.