# Upload file to Google Drive with React and Google App script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-apps-script

I am trying to upload file with Google App script and React.

Google Script:

```
function uploadArquivoParaDrive(base64Data, nomeArq, idPasta) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
    type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(nomeArq);

    var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(idPasta).createFile(ss);

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Erro: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

I can run this ant it works:

```
function uploadFile() {
  var image =   UrlFetchApp.fetch('url to some image').getBlob();
  var file = {
    title: 'google_logo.png',
    mimeType: 'image/png'
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, image);
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.fileSize);
}
```

This is React script:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.get(url, {...this.state}, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })

};

 setFile = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.files)
     this.setState({file: event.target.files[0]});
};

render() {

    return (
        <form>
            <input type="file" id="file" onChange={this.setFile} />
            <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>ADD</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

I am trying with `POST`, but I am getting 400 response. I know that this can't be GET request, but and with it, I am getting - 200 with no response.

I can insert rows in sheets, but I want to upload files to Google Drive with `Google App Scripts`.

I know that there is a way to upload files via Google Scripts and React, because, there is a way without React (`google.script.run`).

Comment: Where is the server receiver script `doPost()`?

Comment: Hi, but how to send request with the file to `doPost()` ?

Comment: First, where is your POST receiver? There should be a doPost() function server side to receive the file. Where is it? Second, I don't think ``multipart/form-data`` works with file, you need to send it as ``application/x-www-form-urlencoded`` or file part in the multipart data's header shouldn't have `filename:`, so that the data isn't interpreted as a file server side, but as blob data

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different approaches that are used in mixed mode. It's unacceptable in some contexts.

Let's say softly 'React is a dummy'. This is an add-on that you should always avoid when somewhat comes to something that you depend on, but you cannot change. See what [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) is.

*Below it is always assumed that you are working in a browser. Your web-pages are hosted in the web application of the Google Apps Script.*

### The first approach. Using XMLHttpRequests

On client side you have to use XMLHttpRequests call from your browser.

On server side you have to use `doGet` `doPost` reserved functions. Always transfer data in a clear and simple format. This will save time searching for errors.

Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300412/1393023

### The second approach. Using Client-side API

On client side you have to use `google.script.run` call from your browser.

On server side you have to use your functions. Always transfer data in a clear and simple format. This will save time searching for errors.

Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/15790713/1393023

### Consequence

Your example has signs of mixing approaches. Unfortunately, it cannot be quickly debugged.

There is no reason that React is causing the problem. If so, then your architecture is incorrect.

If you want to use `axios`, then you need to consider the first approach.

If you want to use `google.script.run` then you need to catch `onSubmit` then you need to call an interface that implement `google.script.run`. Usually asynchronously, since the last call will still be completed with a callback.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I need to use React. Your solution with the button and inline function is one way to do things and it can be implemented, but will be little complicated, because there is and another data + file upload, which I need to process at once.  The first approach will be the best way will be the best. May be need somehow to implement Google API JS library.